# Review action on reject HTML / Frontend Bug

Tags: bug, rejected-edits

When I review a suggested edit, hit Reject, the new window appears and the Reject button turns to state disabled and value "Rejecting...", when I discard the window where I chose the reasons to reject (without selecting one), the Rejecting... button does not change its state back to enabled and value "Reject".

[image]

Update:

I'm using vanilla Firefox 25.0.1

Comment: Just noticed the original got wrong tags, going to fix it now and hopefully less dupes will popup.